# Secure PHP JSON output result on web server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, phonegap

Im building the app with phonegap, App Submits and fetch the data from MySQL database located on server(website). IM successful submitting the data and fetching the data on app.

Fetching the data by ajax from location on my webserver by php file (www.example.com/fetch.php). But when I visit the same file from browser it shows complete database exposed in json format.

Is there any way I can secure the data? or use any token or authentication only to access for my app and on browser it doesn't allow to view?

Appreciate your help in adv

Comment: hand the file back via php and block the file type from being accessed by the server.  This way your php script that hands the file can be set to only be accessed by people who should be able to see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add additional data send to your server. A token or validation will do.

Then add your condition before echoing your json data.

Example:
   Set your token from app to be send to your server (ex. token is '12345'), So that your server know that the request was from your app. Then add this code to your server.

```
$token = intval($_POST['token']); // if you are using POST Method, but you can change it to $_GET if you are using GET method.

if($token == '12345'){
  echo json_encode($your_json_data);
}else{
  //display something
}
```

Or try this to your server side

```
if(isset($_GET['hash'])){
      echo json_encode($your_json_data);
    }else{
      //display something
    }
```

Comment: OK an How can I add this token through my ajax ? 
Currently I have ajax in below format:

$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data : { getContent : true, hash : '0800fc577294c34e0b28ad2839435945' },
        url: "http://example.com/gap/json.php",
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(result){

       and so on...

Comment: on ajax call it shows : Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0
What could be the issue ?

Comment: I think I have a typo here. @VickyParab You can directly add this `data : { getContent : true, hash : '0800fc577294c34e0b28ad2839435945' },` to `data : { getContent : true, hash : '0800fc577294c34e0b28ad2839435945', token: '12345' }`

Comment: first one worked for me, I just messed up with GET & POST, I was using get method, changing methond on server side it worked. 
Thanx a lot for your help! Appreciate.

Comment: Yes, I will follow that for secret key, Thanx